# Url Hack not showing prefilled value on custom Visualforce page with custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, urlhacking

I Have a simple visualforce page on which ik want to prefill a lookup field with a contactid to create a new record. I used the Id of the customfield Contactpersoon__c and used CF before the lookup ID as I found in the documetation of URL Hacking. I added a contactid as value ending with _lkid as it is a lookup according to URL hacking.

My page loads without the field beiing prefilled why is this not working?

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Relatie_Contact__c"  showHeader="false"   applyBodyTag="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <apex:sectionHeader title="" subtitle="Relatie contact"/>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>       
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Relatie_Contact__c}" var="r"  >
                        <apex:column style="width:250px">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Contactpersoon</apex:facet> 
                            <apex:inputField value="{!r.Contactpersoon__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column style="width:250px">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Relatiesoort</apex:facet> 
                            <apex:inputField value="{!r.Relatiesoort__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column style="width:250px">
                            <apex:facet name="header">Organisatie</apex:facet> 
                            <apex:inputField value="{!r.Organisatie__c}"/> 
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

URL:

```
var url = '/apex/NieuweRelatie?CF00N5800000BNqkB=0039E00000LifHz_lkid';
```

Comment: you need to pass both name and Id as params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both field value and Id needs to be passed to prefill the reference record details:

```
<field_id>=<parentRecord_Name>&<field_id>_lkid=<parentRecord_Id>
```

Where

- field_id = reference field Id
- parentRecord_Name = record name to be displayed on the field. You will need to use **URLENCODE** the string.
- parentRecord_Id = Id of the parent record to which the entered record should be the child.